# How to pass two/mulitple object to a function as parameter

Tags: javascript

I am able to get the fist parameter `iAmDog` and the first parameter is also accessed by `this`, how to pass second parameter `iAmCat` and print them?

```js
var speak = function(iAmDog, iAmCat) {
  console.log(this);

  console.log(iAmDog.love);
  console.log(iAmDog.normal);

  console.log(iAmCat.love);
  console.log(iAmCat.normal);
};

var speakAsDog = {
  normal: "moof",
  love: 'woow'
};
var speakAsCat = {
  normal: "meow",
  love: 'purr'
};

speak.call(speakAsDog, speakAsCat);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The very first parameter in `function.call` and `function.apply` is the `thisArg` which is available as `this` value inside function. So if you want to pass any arguments you should start from second. in you case you can send null as `thisArg` because this is not referenced inside function.

```js
var speak = function(iAmDog, iAmCat) {
  console.log(iAmDog.love);
  console.log(iAmDog.normal);

  console.log(iAmCat.love);
  console.log(iAmCat.normal);
};

var speakAsDog = { normal: "moof", love: 'woow' };
var speakAsCat = { normal: "meow", love: 'purr' };

speak.call(null, speakAsDog, speakAsCat);
speak.apply(null, [speakAsDog, speakAsCat]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is just riddled with typos. Also, you don't have to explicitly call the `.call()` function.

```js
var speak = function (iAmDog, iAmCat) {
  console.log(iAmDog.love);
  console.log(iAmDog.normal);

  console.log(iAmCat.love);
  console.log(iAmCat.normal);
};

var speakAsDog = { normal: "moof", love: 'woow' };
var speakAsCat = { normal: "meow", love: 'purr' };

speak(speakAsDog, speakAsCat);
```

Comment: Hey @FrankerZ in the question he already refered, first parameter is also accessed by `this`. How this solution might help in changing the context ? Here `this` will point to the outer scope. Let me know if I am missing here somehting.

Comment: He just wants to access the parameter. There is no need for `this` at all.

Comment: Please check his first line of question.. 
> am able to get the fist parameter iAmDog and the first parameter is also accessed by this
he had a requirement to access it using this.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by FrankerZ you might not need `call` or `apply` But in case you need context variable being changed, 
You can use `call` or

```js
var speak = function(iAmCat) {
  var iAmDog = this;
  console.log(iAmDog.love);
  console.log(iAmDog.normal);

  console.log(iAmCat.love);
  console.log(iAmCat.normal);
};

var speakAsDog = {
  normal: "moof",
  love: 'woow'
};
var speakAsCat = {
  normal: "meow",
  love: 'purr'
};

speak.call(speakAsDog, speakAsCat);
```

use `apply` or

```js
var speak = function() {
  var iAmDog = this,
    iAmCat = arguments[0];
  console.log(iAmDog.love);
  console.log(iAmDog.normal);

  console.log(iAmCat.love);
  console.log(iAmCat.normal);
};

var speakAsDog = {
  normal: "moof",
  love: 'woow'
};
var speakAsCat = {
  normal: "meow",
  love: 'purr'
};

speak.apply(speakAsDog, [speakAsCat]);
```

use `bind`.

```js
var speak = function(iAmCat) {
  var iAmDog = this;
  console.log(iAmDog.love);
  console.log(iAmDog.normal);

  console.log(iAmCat.love);
  console.log(iAmCat.normal);
};

var speakAsDog = {
  normal: "moof",
  love: 'woow'
};
var speakAsCat = {
  normal: "meow",
  love: 'purr'
};
var newFN = speak.bind(speakAsDog);
newFN(speakAsCat);
```

Comment: Hey @Syed as you wanted to use `this` in a different context, you can use `call`, `apply` or `bind` shown avobe to get the result.